# Highcharts not displaying with csv/json and Flask

Tags: jquery, highcharts, flask

so basically ive been trying to use Flask to display charts in a 2x3 grid. (6 charts in total) but i cant even get one up.

Im looking at this one: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

The default example seems to work. However, but when i host my own data at localhost:5000/data and use highcharts to load it, nothing appears at all. I think the data is the wrong format.

my data is of the form

```
{'2016-04-22': 3,
'2016-04-25': 1,
'2016-04-26': 1,
'2016-04-29': 12,
'2016-05-03': 2}
```

but the data in that link is

```
?([
[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,4),0.7645],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,5),0.7638]]
```

Here's a fiddle link (ignore data.csv, its supposed to be data)
https://jsfiddle.net/d8xgno5d/

Anyone got any pointers? really desperate now. I've tried csv, but i dont know how to load csv data from a link into highchars.

all help will really be appreciated :)

thank you! :)

Comment: When you provide a fiddle, make sure its working please.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! :) may i ask what do you mean by its working? it's not working thats why im kind of posting here :(

Comment: It's not working in the sense that you haven't included the jQuery or highcharts library and you're referring to a resource on your localhost which we cannot access. We can't help if there's no way to see what the problem is.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/d8xgno5d/2/ for an update which includes relevant libraries and update your question if it's indeed what your issue really is.

Comment: thanks alot for the update! :) my question is:

1) when i use json, nothing appears at all. probably due to a data format difference as spoken above

2) when i use csv, i dont know how to load it into highcharts from a link, which ive hosted on localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, I managed to solve it for the load csv method.

By replacing the first line of .getJSON with

```
 $.get('http://localhost:5000/data.csv',function(csv){
```

you can load CSV's instead, which is much easier when you can use pandas in python.

Here's the full code for the javascript file if needed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.get('http://localhost:5000/data.csv',function(csv){
        $('#workload').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            data: {
                csv: csv
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Evie Workload'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                        'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Emails'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },

            credits:{
                enabled:false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 2
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'Workload',
            }]
        });
    });
});
```